# optimize.newton issue with arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, scipy

This is my first time using the `optimize.newton` function. I am defining a
couple of functions (`LHS`, `RHS`) along with their integral (`result_LHS`,
`result_RHS`). I am using the result_LHS and result_RHS functions as to define a
new function (called `function`) for which I want to find the zero (`T_a`).

---

```
alb = 0.2 #constant albedo
F = 866 #J/s*m**2
R = 287 #J/K*kg
U = 5 #m/s
C_p = 1000 #J/K*kg
C_d = 0.0015
p1 = 10**4
p2 = 10**5
p3 = 10**6 #Pa
sig = 5.67*10**-8 #J/s*m**2*K**4 #Stefan-Boltzmann cst
def rho(T_a):
        return p1/(R*T_a)      #FIRST USING P = 10**4 Pa
def a(T_a):
        return rho(T_a)*C_p*C_d*U



x0=230

def LHS(theta):
    return (1-alb)*F*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)

def result_LHS(theta):
    return integrate.quad(lambda theta: LHS(theta), 0, pi/2)

def T_g(theta, T_a):
    return np.roots(array([(sig),0,0,(a(T_a)),((-a(T_a)*T_a)-LHS(theta))]))[3]

def RHS(theta,T_a):
    return sig*T_g(theta,T_a)**4*np.cos(theta)

def result_RHS(theta,T_a):
    return integrate.quad(lambda theta: RHS(theta,T_a), -pi/2, pi/2)

def function(theta,T_a):
    return 1-((result_LHS(theta)/result_RHS(theta,T_a)))

T_a_0 = scipy.optimize.newton(function,x0,fprime=None,args=(theta,),tol=(10**-5))
print T_a_0
```

---

Here is what it outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jadecheclair/Documents/PHY479Y/T_gvstheta.py", line 167, in <module>
    T_a_0 = scipy.optimize.newton(function,x0,fprime=None,args=(theta,),tol=(10**-5))
NameError: name 'theta' is not defined
```

I was thinking I might need to define my theta, which would be
`theta=np.arange(-pi/2, pi/2, pi/20)`. But since I am using it as a variable of integration in "result_LHS" and "result_RHS" integration functions, I think it should remain a variable. Then how come python doesn't accept the fact that theta is a variable and needs to define it?

I would greatly appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you post runnable code since a random choice of constants may lead to other errors.

Comment: The code you included in the question shows `args=(theta,)`, but the code shown in the error message shows `args=(theta)`.  You need that comma in there.

Comment: (You have changed the question, so I deleted my old answer.)  When you say `args=(theta,)`, it means that `theta` (which must be defined when you use it) holds the *extra* arguments that are passed to the object function.  It is the *first* variable of `function` that will be varied (starting with `x0`) to find the root.  So your choice of variable names looks backwards: you define `function(theta, T_a)`, but you give `args=(theta,)` to `newton`, which will assign `theta` (whatever it is) to `T_a`.